# Get the TabHost from Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I have a class that extends Fragment like this:

```
public class Fragment_Coupons extends Fragment {
    TabHost tabHost;
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;

    public Fragment_Coupons() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_coupon, container,
                false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And the XML file for this is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</TabHost>
```

Now I want to get the

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
```

Which is giving me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();
```

Comment: make it sure that you are calling android.R.id.tabHost, not /*your-package-name*/.R.id.tabHost

Comment: I am using tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost); but its not working

Comment: Did you extend your activity with tabActivity?